# how can I make my particle affects not glow?

Tags: particles

I am making a scene with a particle effect system in it, and I am wondering how I can take away the glow from the object. It is really bright, and it is not intended to look like that. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Emitter particles, you have to change the render type from Halo to something like Object, and use an object like a cube with a non Halo material on it.

[image: Emitter Settings]